# How can I fill an SVG path on hover with CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to add a hover state to a button. When the button is hovered, I want the SVG path to fill and animate like this:

[image]
[image]

How can I achieve this with CSS please? This is the SVG code:

```html
<svg 
    width="22"
    height="42"
    viewBox="0 0 22 42"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
    <path 
        d="M1 41C12.0457 41 21 32.0457 21 21C21 9.9543 12.0457 1 1 1"
        stroke="#00A9E0"
        stroke-width="2"
        stroke-linecap="round" 
    />
</svg>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [ask]. We're not a free coding service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animated SVG, circle stroke hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844333/animated-svg-circle-stroke-hover)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` on hover:

```css
svg path {
  stroke-dasharray: 50;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
}

svg:hover path {
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg 
    width="22"
    height="42"
    viewBox="0 0 22 42"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
    <path 
        d="M1 41C12.0457 41 21 32.0457 21 21C21 9.9543 12.0457 1 1 1"
        stroke="#00A9E0"
        stroke-width="2"
        stroke-linecap="round" 
    />
</svg>
```